# Create random objects in java

Tags: java, math, random, percentage

I have an array and I want to fill it with Random objects, but with a specific percentage of each object. For example i have Rectangle, Circle and Cylinder. I want the Rectangle to be the 40% of array's length, and Circle and Cylinder 30% each. Any ideas?

This code will have a 40% posibility to generate Rectangle etc..

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
     n = UserInput.getInteger();
     Shape[] array = new Shape[n];


            for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            double rnd = Math.random();

            if (rnd<=0.4) {
            array[i] = new Rectangle();
        }


            else if (rnd>0.4 && rnd<=0.7){
            array[i] = new Circle();
        }

            else {
            array[i] = new Cylinder();
      }
```

Comment: yes I have ideas, but it needs your code to be seen

Comment: This is somewhat ambiguous, do you want *exactly* 40% to be filled with `Rectangle`s or do you want that to be the expected value?

Comment: Is the array length known?

Comment: the array length will be given by the user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something along the lines of

```
for each v in array,
    x = rand()  // number between 0 and 1, see Math.random()
    if 0 < x < 0.40, then set v to Rectangle;  // 40% chance of this
    if 0.40 < x < 0.70, then set v to Circle;  // 30% chance of this
    otherwise set v to Cylcinder               // 30% chance of this
```

Of course, this will not ensure *exact* ratios, but rather just certain expected ratios. If you want your array to consist of exactly 40% rectangles, for instance, you can populate 40% of it with rectangles (and 30% with circles and 30% with cylinders) and then use

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array))
```

Comment: But this may not mean that exactly 40% would be Rectangle, 30 % would be Circle and same for cylinder.

Comment: @sleekFish The question is ambiguous in that regard; does the OP want exactly 40% or does he want that to be the expected value?

Comment: I want exactly 40%. For example in an array[10] I want 4 rectangles, 3 circles and 3 cylinders.

Answer (score 1):

I think You can do it something like:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;

public Shape[] ArrayRandomizer(int size) {
    List<Shape> list = new ArrayList<Shape>();
    if (size < 10 && size%10 != 0) {
        return null; // array must be divided by 10 without modulo
    }
    else {
        Random random = new Random();
        Shape[] result = new Shape[size];
        for (int r=0; r<4*(size/10); r++) {
            Shape rectangle = new Rectangle(random.nextInt(), random.nextInt(), random.nextInt(), random.nextInt()); // standart awt constructor
            list.add(rectangle);
        }
        for (int cir=0; cir<3*(size/10); cir++) {
            Shape circle = new Circle(random.nextInt(), random.nextInt(), random.nextInt()); // your constructor of circle like Circle(int x, int y, int radius)
            list.add(circle);
        }
        for (int cil=0; cil<3*(size/10); cil++) {
            Shape cilinder = new Cilinder(random.nextInt(), random.nextInt(), random.nextInt(), random.nextInt()); // your constructor of cilinder like Cilinder (int x, int y, int radius, int height)
            list.add(cilinder);
        }
    }
    Shape[] result = list.toArray(new Shape[list.size()]);

    return  result;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to bound the coordinates of the rectangles, circles, and cylinders.  It won't do much good if the shapes are off-screen. Does the OP want only integer coordinates and sizes?

Comment: Without going into the details of pseudorandom numbers generation))

Comment: I know; non-integer sizes for rectangles (or even ones with sides not parallel to the axes) lead to discretization errors.  I'm guessing I was too zealous in my query.  But bounding the shapes is important.  `nextInt()` ranges from `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.